# List of deprecated Cordova versions

Tags: cordova

I am using cordova 4.0.0 for my project now and migrating to the latest version because Google is blocking applications less than Cordova 4.1.1.
I would like to know if Apache Cordova has marked any of the versions of Cordova as deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, I don't see any notification from  Apache cordova that marked any version of cordova as deprecated. Infact, i did see many users in SO posting queries related to cordova 3x as well.

In fact, all i could manage to pull out from the net related to cordova depredations is this [link](https://wiki.apache.org/cordova/DeprecationPolicy) from their offical wiki page. Hope it helps.